# Consolidate data in more that one column

Tags: libreoffice-calc, consolidation

I have the below dataset:

```
gene# (cell A)  Databases (cell B)
1               Uniref
2               Genemark
3               GeneBank
3               Swissprot
4               Uniref
4               Swissprot
4               GeneBank
5               Swissprot
```

I am wondering if there is a way to use the consolidate feature to separate in different columns the above dataset as following:

```
(Cell_A)   (Cell_B)    (Cell_C)   (Cell_D)
1          Uniref
2          Genemark
3          GeneBank    Swissprot
4          Uniref      GeneBank   Swissprot
5          Swissprot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution on my own: 
-I applied a filter in the second column, and I generated into another sheet the four columns I want. 
-After that, I used in a **fifth cell(named counter)** the function wizard of COUNTBLANK for the **second,** the **third** and the **forth** column which gave me a number range between 0-3. Those numbers are corresponding to the empty cells. 
-Finally, I applied a sort filter in the **counter cell** and selected the numbers 0,1 and 2 and voila!